# Are event receivers supposed to handle events of editing the list itself?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, event-receivers

I just noticed that our list item event receivers are running when we are updating the list itself, like changing the description or the title. I thought these should only trigger when modifying list items in the list, and not that they would trigger on modifications on the list itself.

Is this expected behavior or have we configured something strange here?

Google isn't giving me much.

Comment: Can you make sure you do not have any List Event Receiver attached with the list?

Comment: @LittSpector Sorry for late response, I have only ItemAdding, ItemUpdating, ItemAdded and ItemUpdated on that list.

Answer (score 1):

No List updating ER based on [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceivertype?view=sharepoint-server#Microsoft_SharePoint_SPEventReceiverType_ItemAdded), but you may have field ER attached to the list.

You could try to use PowerShell to check the ER(s) attached to your list.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://SharePointSite/"
$web = $site.RootWeb
$list = $web.Lists["ListTitle"]
$list.EventReceivers | Select assembly, name, type
```

Comment: Using this I only see that I have ItemAdding, ItemUpdating, ItemAdded and ItemUpdated on that list. But when I update the title of the list itself, it's triggering ItemUpdating and then errors because we have code that crash when this happens.